# multiple calls to cURL

Tags: php, curl

I have a page on which a `cURL` is performed and takes a few seconds to complete.
I was wondering what would happen at the server if few users accessed that page at the same time.
My guess is that each user will be given his/hers own time (say 5 seconds), but it should not affect each others waiting time, or should it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course. Because it's multithreaded. Requests don't interfer between each other (if they are not too many)

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on resources.

If the processing of your requests takes five seconds because of heavy file I/O, simultaneous requests might slow down the other ones, doubling the time required for each requests.

Same goes for bandwidth: is it a lot of data you're requesting? Then multiple simultaneous requests might impact each other, given a maximum bandwidth the upstream server can assign to a single connection and its total bandwidth.

Furthermore, when the processing of the (result of the) request takes up a (relative) lot of processor time, firing multiple request at one can slow down each request.

Comment: I use curl_init and curl_close about 5-6 times. Each of them takes time to reach the server,process and come back.

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to say because there are too many unknown factors¹, most notably the number of users hitting you within any one 5 sec interval. But for a sanely small number of users it should be fine.

¹ For example: how many requests can/will your setup serve concurrently? what about the remote `curl` target?